# Laravel DB and Eloquent design

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have read front to back the Eloquent documentation and have looked through many different tutorials (including several hours of nettuts). I have some basic db design questions that relate to the Eloquent model. I would love it if someone could help me make sense.

So this database has Users, Partners, and Events

```
Users
---------
id
userName
firstName
lastName

Partners
---------
id
user_id
firstName
lastName

Events
---------
id
user_id
partner_id
description
```

So this is a very basic layout for the purpose of this question. Obviously there will be additional fields placed in each table that give more information (including timestamps, etc).

Each user can have many partners
Each partner has only one user
Each partner has many events

With this basic layout I need to know if I am on the right track in particular with the Events table. There will be times when I need to view all recent events that are associated with the User and also pull data from the partners table (like their firstName and lastName).

So here is my relationship understanding..

*User hasMany Partners*

*Partners hasMany Events*

*Events belongTo User & belongTo Partner*

Will this setup allow me to make simple eloquent calls?

Here are the models as I understand them:

USERS

```
class Users extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'Users';
public $timestamps = true;

public function Partners()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Partners', 'user_id');
}

public function Events()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Events', 'Partners');
}

}
```

PARTNERS

```
class Partners extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'Partners';
public $timestamps = true;

public function Partners()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Users', 'id');
}

public function Events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Events', 'id');
}

}
```

EVENTS

```
class Events extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'Events';
public $timestamps = true;

public function Users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Users', 'id');
}

public function Partners()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Partners', 'id');
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you can setup any/all these relations with your schema:

(All simplified to keep it's short, but obviously they are all methods returning relation. Also I include foreign keys, since your examples are wrong, where you put `id` as 2nd param, and I encourage to use singular names for models)

```
// User model

partners { hasMany('Partner', 'user_id') }

// events through partners table and partner_id foreign key
partnersEvents { hasManyThrough('Event', 'Partner') }

// events by user_id foreign key
events { hasManyThrough('Event', 'Partner') }

// many to many with events being pivot table
partnersThroughPivot { belongsToMany('Partner', 'events') }
```

---

```
// Partner model

user { belongsTo('User', 'user_id') }

// events through partners table and partner_id foreign key
events { hasMany('Event', 'partner_id') }

// many to many with events being pivot table
usersThroughPivot { belongsToMany('User', 'events') }
```

---

```
// Event model

user { belongsTo('User', 'user_id') }

partner { belongsTo('Partner', 'partner_id') }
```